# NullPointer location on JavaFX FXMLLoader

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javafx, fxmlloader

I've read through all of the issues about this on stackoverflow, and I haven't used something that worked. I have a basic fxml that is built using the JavaFX Scene Builder 1.1 while using Java 1.7.

I just want to load the file... but everything seems to point to a null location meaning that it cant find it. I don't understand why. I have 18 try/catches to show 18 different possibilities for it to work under, but it cant find it. These examples are pulled from some of the stackoverflow questions as 'valid accepted answers'. What am I missing something here? Everything compiles, so I dont think I'm missing a SDK or something major.

The log prints 1 to 18, with a NullPointerException on the 18th try/catch that says NullPointer... location is required.

[View post on imgur.com](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bj5BI.jpg)

[image]

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;

import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.net.URL;


public class OptionsToggleMenu  extends Application {

public void launchTheThing(String... args){     //runs this on the Main application's main method.
    launch(args);
}

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    int failures = 0;

    try{
        Parent root1 = new Parent() {
        };
        try{
              root1 = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("AdventureLibrary/test.fxml"));
            System.out.println(null == root1);
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println(1);
            failures++;
        }

        try{
              Parent root2 = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("AdventureLibrary/test.fxml"));
            System.out.println(null == root2);
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println(2);
            failures++;
        }

        try{
              Parent root2 = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("bin/test.fxml"));
            System.out.println(null == root2);
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println(3);
            failures++;
        }

        try{
              Parent root2 = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("bin/test.fxml"));
            System.out.println(null == root2);
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println(4);
            failures++;
        }

        try{
              Parent root2 = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("test.fxml"));
            System.out.println(null == root2);
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println(5);
            failures++;
        }

        try{
              Parent root2 = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("test.fxml"));
            System.out.println(null == root2);
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println(6);
            failures++;
        }
        try{
              root1 = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/AdventureLibrary/test.fxml"));
            System.out.println(null == root1);
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println(7);
            failures++;
        }

        try{
              Parent root2 = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("/AdventureLibrary/test.fxml"));
            System.out.println(null == root2);
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println(8);
            failures++;
        }

        try{
              Parent root2 = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/bin/test.fxml"));
            System.out.println(null == root2);
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println(9);
            failures++;
        }

        try{
              Parent root2 = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("/bin/test.fxml"));
            System.out.println(null == root2);
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println(10);
            failures++;
        }

        try{
              Parent root2 = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/test.fxml"));
            System.out.println(null == root2);
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println(11);
            failures++;
        }

        try{
              Parent root2 = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("/test.fxml"));
            System.out.println(null == root2);
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println(12);
            failures++;
        }
        try{
              root1 = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/resources/test.fxml"));
            System.out.println(null == root1);
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println(13);
            failures++;
        }

        try{
              Parent root2 = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("/resources/test.fxml"));
            System.out.println(null == root2);
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println(14);
            failures++;
        }

        try{
              Parent root2 = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("resources/test.fxml"));
            System.out.println(null == root2);
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println(15);
            failures++;
        }

        try{
              Parent root2 = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("resources/test.fxml"));
            System.out.println(null == root2);
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println(16);
            failures++;
        }

        try{
              Parent root2 = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("test.fxml"));
            System.out.println(null == root2);
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println(17);
            failures++;
        }

        try{
              Parent root2 = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("/test.fxml"));
            System.out.println(null == root2);
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println(18);
            System.out.println(e);
            failures++;
        }


        System.out.println("There are this many failures: " + failures+"/18");

    Scene scene = new Scene(root1, 300, 275);

    primaryStage.setTitle("FXML Welcome");
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("XX"+e);
    }
}


}
```

Edit: Adding code that calls on resources/fxml/test.fxml is unsuccessful as well.
[image]

Comment: What is the stack trace of the error?

Comment: Which, if any, of the test.fxml files are copied to the deployment directory, and where are they in that directory structure?

Comment: No stack trace gets printed with the catch's excepting just merely printing "java.lang.NullPointerException: Location is required."... that error is on the 18th try-catch but if I fill ito ut, will say that error for each try-catch above.

Comment: @James_D, isn't putting the test.fxml files under the project name AdventureLibrary good enough? When I click run-debug in IDEA, it generates this issue.

Comment: 1. It's not printing the stack trace because you're not asking it to. Replace `System.out.println(e);` with `e.printStackTrace();` (though I don't think this is useful...) 2. I'm not that familiar with IntelliJ, so I don't know it's exact build behavior, but the point is the fxml file needs to be available at runtime. All you are showing is the source code directory, which is obviously pretty much irrelevant if the issue is that the fxml file can't be found at runtime. What does the deployment directory structure look like, and where are the fxml file(s) in it?

Comment: I found where the build output is... and there is no .fxml files or olders in here other than the classes that I use. This is inconvienent, but I added the .fxml file and now the errors print 14/18... so at least 4 try/catch statements worked. Thanks.

Comment: Probably you just need to clean and rebuild the project. It may be that having multiple fxml files with the same name (and possibly targeted to the same location relative to the class path) is confusing the build process - I would reduce it to just one, probably the one just under `src/resources`, then clean and rebuild.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fully solve this issue, I took James_D's post and checked how IDEA's build to production works. It doesn't save files unless you tell it to. There are several default files that the compiler will bring to production like .property and .jpg files... but not JavaFX files like that end in .fxml.

I followed this: https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/resource-files.html
I was able to get a build to deploy my fxml file once I appened ?*.fxml at the end of the compile line for accepted files.

Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to change this line:

```
root1 = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("AdventureLibrary/test.fxml"));
```

I do not think that is the correct path to your FXML.  In my project we use

```
resources
    ->fxml
        text.fxml
```

We load it like this:

```
FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
loader.load(Class.class.getClassLoader().getResource("fxml/text.fxml").openStream());
```